# gnuplot abbreviation reference

Tags: shortcuts, gnuplot

Where are the gnuplot abbreviations specifically documented?
For example:- the single letter "l" command.
 `> help l`
gives a big list and does not identify what the single letter "L" command is expanded to.
This question comes from reading posted example scripts & is related to [Looking up gnuplot abbreviations](https://superuser.com/questions/508644/looking-up-gnuplot-abbreviations) which does not clarify how the single letter abbreviations are disambiguated.
Many thanks, hope the answer helps others

Comment: How does [Looking up gnuplot abbreviations](http://superuser.com/questions/508644/looking-up-gnuplot-abbreviations) not answer your question?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/508644/looking-up-gnuplot-abbreviations does not explain where to find out what the ambiguous single letter abbreviatons reesolve to. e.g. "P" could reslove to "Pause", "Plot", "Print", or "Pwd".

Comment: @mjp Now there are [ [1](http://superuser.com/a/1098570/257269), [2](http://superuser.com/a/1099426/257269) ]. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Autoextracted list of gnuplot command abbreviations from source code

> ```
>        bi - bind 
>        ca - call 
>        cl - clear 
>      eval - evaluate 
>        ex - exit 
>         f - fit 
>         h - help 
>        hi - history 
>         l - load 
>       low - lower 
>         p - plot 
>        pa - pause 
>        pr - print 
>  printerr - printerror 
>         q - quit 
>        ra - raise 
>        re - reread 
>       ref - refresh 
>       rep - replot 
>       res - reset 
>        sa - save 
>       scr - screendump 
>        se - set 
>        sh - show 
>       she - shell 
>        sp - splot 
>        st - stats 
>        sy - system 
>       und - undefine 
>       uns - unset 
>        up - update
> ```

Many thanks to https://superuser.com/users/257269/hastur for the inspiration!
I trust this reference is useful.

The exact abbreviation priority may vary with each version of gnuplot.  It was extracted from the tarball with the following sh script (or similar).

```
# Extract file --to-stdout -O
# Specifically select the command table
# Grep commands
# Remove { } syntax, commas & double quotes
# Print abbr & full command
# sort
tar -xv -O -f /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/gnuplot/5.0.3/gnuplot-5.0.3.tar.gz  gnuplot-5.0.3/src/tables.c | \
  sed -n '/command_ftbl\[\]/,/invalid_command/p'                        | \
  grep '\$'                                                             | \
  sed 's/{//g ; s/}//g ; s/,/ /g ; s/"//g'                              | \
  awk '{split ($1,a, "$"); printf ("%10s - %s \n", a[1],a[1]a[2] ) }'   | \
  sort -bf
```

The commands are stored in the array command_ftbl[], command options etc are in other tables, but once you know the command, the documentation usually makes the option abbreviations clear.